# How to add the "provider" info for an eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

When i have my custom plugin installed, i go into `Eclipse Installation Details > Plugins` Section, where i can see all plugins installed, my plugin has no entry in the "provider" section. How can i set the provider info for my plugin?
I know, you can specify that somehow when you create a new Plugin in the wizard, but how can i set that after or during the development?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "provider name" is stored in a plug-in's manifest (`manifest.mf` file); it's the header named `Bundle-Vendor:`. If you edit the `plugin.xml` or `manifest.mf` files in your plug-in project, [the Manifest editor](http://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.pde.doc.user%2Fguide%2Ftools%2Feditors%2Fmanifest_editor%2Feditor.htm) has a place to enter it on [the **Overview** tab](http://help.eclipse.org/neon/topic/org.eclipse.pde.doc.user/guide/tools/editors/manifest_editor/overview.htm?cp=4_3_2_0_0); the field is labeled **Vendor**.

Comment: Thanks that's it ! 
Wouldn't have expected that with the title "Vendor".